# ggplot2 segment -- direction when x-axis is time

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, lubridate

I have a wind speed and direction times series and I am trying to make a plot that uses line segments to depict the windspeed and direction.  I need to have a basic point scatter plot of windspeed vs time (which I can create) with a line segment from each point (which is where I am getting hung up.)  The length of the line has to be proportional to the windspeed and the angle needs to the wind direction.  I am using ggplot2 with the geom_segment, but because x is time I cannot figure the right formula to use for xend.

Here is an example of the dataframe:

DateTime                WINDSPEED_MPH   DIR

8/29/2008 0:00                 4.28        231

8/29/2008 1:00                 3.11        236

8/29/2008 2:00                 1.36        237

8/29/2008 3:00                 2.92        153

8/29/2008 4:00                 1.94        314

8/29/2008 5:00                 3.11        293

Here is my code so far:

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(lubridate)

Gustav <- read.csv("C:/Users/ezco3/My Research/LPBF/Pontchartrain-Maurepas Surge Consortium/Projects/Lake Tilting Effect Graphic/Datasets/Gustav_NewCanal_Hydro&Metero.csv")

Gustav$TS <- as.POSIXct(Gustav$DateTime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="America/Chicago")
Gustav$DelY <- Gustav$WINDSPEED_MPH*sin(Gustav$DIR)/max(Gustav$WINDSPEED_MPH, na.rm=TRUE)
Gustav$DelX <- Gustav$WINDSPEED_MPH*cos(Gustav$DIR)/max(Gustav$WINDSPEED_MPH, na.rm=TRUE)

plt1 <- ggplot(data = Gustav, aes(x = TS, y =WINDSPEED_MPH))
plt1 + geom_point(color="blue") + 
  geom_segment(data = Gustav, mapping=aes(x= TS, y = WINDSPEED_MPH, xend = TS + 18000*DelX, 
               yend=WINDSPEED_MPH + 5*DelY),size=.1,color="red")
```

And, that creates this:
[image]

The 18000 in front of DelX and the 5 in front of DelY are both arbitrary numbers that I found through trail and error.  Basically, initially using just DelX and DelY (without multipliers) the lines were short and vertical, so I worked through different option until I found this pair which showed some direction to the line.

However, the angles are not correct.  At this stage, I do not understand how units work with time series objects in lubridate so I am lost as to how to figure the correct formula for xend.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data for us to work with? Just paste the output of `dput(Gustav)` into your question. You don't need to paste the whole thing. 10 or 20 rows (e.g., `dput(Gustav[1:20,])`) should be enough.

Comment: Your angles appear to be stretched so that the segments are pointed up or down.  My guess is that this is happening because the units on the x axis are not the same as the units on the y axis.  Is there some factor that relates a units on the x axis and the y axis to a unit on the figure?  Maybe you could then use the different factors instead of 18000.

Comment: It's not the different units per se, but the fact that the range of x values is different from the range of y values. In this case, the x-values are in seconds and the x-axis spans about 864000 seconds (10 days), while the y-axis is in mph and spans about 50 mph. 864000/50 = 17280, close to the 18000 scale factor that the OP came up with. But if, for example, we set the x-axis to be just 50 seconds in length (not that that would be useful here) the direction lines would be scaled properly.

Comment: To properly scale the direction lines, multiply `DelX` by the ratio of range of the xaxis to range of the yaxis. To get this exact, you should use `coord_cartesian` to set the x and y axis ranges and then take the ratio of their ranges as the scale factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the suggestions of @eipi10 to calculate the appropriate ratio and multiply by the change in x but not explicitly setting the coordinate limits, here's a solution that correctly displays wind directions of 45 degrees and the length of the segment corresponds to the windspeed.

```
date <- seq(ymd('2012-04-07'),ymd('2013-03-22'), by = 'day')
windspeed <- rnorm(n = length(date), mean = 5, sd = 1)
dir <- rep((c(0,30,45,60,90)*(pi/180)), times = length(date)/5)

data <- data.frame(date, windspeed, dir)

rat <-as.numeric(interval(min(date), max(date))) / (max(windspeed) - min(windspeed))

data <- data %>%
    mutate(DelY = windspeed * sin(dir)/(2*max(windspeed)),
           DelX  = rat * windspeed * cos(dir)/(2*max(windspeed)))



plt1 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = date, y =windspeed))
plt1 + geom_point(color="blue")+
  geom_segment(aes(x= date, y = windspeed, xend = date + DelX,
                   yend=windspeed + DelY),size=.1,color="red") +
  coord_fixed(ratio = rat)
```

Comment: It just occurred to me that you also need to account for the aspect ratio of the graph when you do the scaling. The method you and I described only works for `coord_fixed(ratio=1)` (meaning one unit in the x and y directions each span the same physical distance on the plot), which isn't very useful when the x and y values span very different ranges. You can see that it doesn't work in general if you create a few different values of `dir` instead of just 45 degrees.

Comment: fortunately this won't be a problems since wind only blows out of the northeast, right?

Comment: what a coincidence this is exactly what I am working on it today. But what if the x and y axis correspond to longitude and latitude. I am trying to figure out how to do it and I just can't get it right.

Comment: hahaha.... not in Louisiana during a Hurricane...  Thank you both @eipi10 & Tedward.  I think this explains everything that I need!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to an alternative to `geom_segment()`, then you can use `geom_text()` with an ANSI (unicode) arrow symbol `→` to get the desired output:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=date, y=windspeed)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(angle=-dir+90), label="→")
```

Comment: I think this might be a really alternative way, but most likely the easiest and best. Works well for me.